# String or byte32 type in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Which type is more expensive for a smart contract? If I just have static text messages to display which type is better?

Comment: bytes32 uses less gas because it fits in a single word of the EVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I just have static text messages to display which type is better?

Clearly if you have static text message,bytes32 is better in terms of Gas.

> pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
> ```
> contract Sample {
>      string constant statictext = "Hello";
>      bytes32 constant statictext1 = "Hello";
>     function  getStatictextasString() constant public  returns(string){
>         return statictext;
>     }
>
>      function  getStatictextasBytes() constant public returns(bytes32){
>         return statictext1;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> From executing the sample contract in remix,the gas cost is less when
>   you use bytes32 compared to string.
>
> bytes32 :21506
>   String  :21934

Answer (score 4):

Bytes32 is going to be better in gas if its not changing. If you want to play around with it, I built a little fiddle of it https://ethfiddle.com/70ipaEIFdk

Byte used 21465 gas

String used 21897 gas

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SampleOverflow {
  string constant statictext = "HelloStackOverFlow";
  bytes32 constant byteText = "HelloStackOverFlow";
  function  getString() payable public  returns(string){
    return statictext;
  }

  function  getByte() payable public returns(bytes32){
    return byteText;
  }
}
```

Get Byte
[image: GetByte]

Get String

[image]
https://ethfiddle.com/70ipaEIFdk

Answer (score 1):

You could use Remix and test the folowing contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;


contract TestContract  {

bytes32 byt;
string str;

function setByte(bytes32 value) public {
   byt = value;
}


function setStr(string value) public {
   str = value;
}

}
```

For the string, this is the output:

> transaction cost     42975 gas
>   execution cost  20871 gas

But I have no idea how to pass bytes32 via Remix